# React-Redux, cannot set a value to an empty string

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I'm using useDispatch hook and I cannot set the string to an empty string. It always sets the value to the last letter.

**App.tsx**

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
dispatch(updateLocation(''));
```

**reducers.tsx**

```
const setLocation = (location = "", action: any) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "Location":
      return action.value || location;
    default:
      return location;
  }
};
```

**action.tsx**

```
export const updateLocation = (location: string) => {
  return {
    type: "Location",
    value: location,
  };
};
```

Comment: What do you mean under last letter? How are you checking that your problem exists ?

Comment: The empty string evaluates to ```false```, so your condition ```action.value || location``` will always return location if the actions.value is an empty string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since empty string is falsely, you always set value of location.

You need to change your reduces code:

```js
const setLocation = (location = "", action: any) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "Location":
      return action.value !== undefined ? action.value : location;
    default:
      return location;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

if action.value is an empty string it will evaluate to false and so location (aka last letter) is returned and not the empty string.

try removing "|| location" from your code.